# Local magento installation issues

Tags: magento2, localhost

I've installed a magento site locally with MAMP and the homepage works. However, when I go to any other page so products for example I'm getting an 404 error.
If I change the url to include index.php it works though.

So for example my homepage url is 
http://localhost:8888/test-site/

If I got to 
http://localhost:8888/test-site/accessories
I'm getting a 404 error

However, if I go to
http://localhost:8888/test-site/index.php/accessories
it works

I've changed the base_url etc. in the db to http://localhost:8888/test-site/ .  so that shouldn't be the issue.
Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: It is .htaccess issue. can you please try with  http://localhost:8888/test-site/index.php/accessories

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for Apache's **mod_rewrite** module. If the module is not installed, please install and enable it first.

Then, you need to login to admin panel and go to **Stores > Configuration**. Under **General > Web** section, change the value of **Use Web server Rewrites** to **`Yes`** and save the configuration.

Flush Magento's Cache and check the frontend now.